# Foreign (non-US) Movie Name tag should be of original title or English dubbed title?

Tags: discussion, tags

After reading [End of Ame Agaru](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/12229/end-of-ame-agaru) question, i edited it to mention the English title of the film in question body but i got confused in creating Tag, I mean what tag should be name [ame-agaru](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ame-agaru) or [after-the-rain](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/after-the-rain). For now Christian Rau has created [after-the-rain](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/after-the-rain) tag and user has requested tag synonym in comments.

But i still want to know what tag should be named for this kind of movies? and What should be done for this kind of questions?

Related: [Reference to original title?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/975/reference-to-original-title)

Comment: What is a *"foreign movie"*, a non-Indian movie (given that this is *your* meta question)? ;)

Comment: @ChristianRau Foreign means non hollywood movie here.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that it probably means *"foreign to the US"*, but still *"foreign"* is a heavily subjective word (even if probably everybody understands how it is meant here), and in fact *Hollywood* movies are quite *"foreign"* to the poster of this particular meta question (and thus the author of the word *"foreign"*). But I'm just nit-picking here. ;)

Answer (score 3):

If these are indeed the same movie, the solution would be to decide what the "primary" tag should be and then create synonyms for the other movie names to that tag.

I would think that choosing which tag gets precedence is going to be something that changes depending on the type of movie. Use these examples;

- In the instance of a movie that was created multiple times (for example "The Ring" and "Ringu"), one with the original cast and one with an American cast in English - in this  this instance I would choose the version of the movie that was most successful as the "primary" movie and create the other versions as synonyms,
- In the instance of a movie that was filmed once and then dubbed over in multiple different languages, with movie titles in different languages for the different releases, I would suggest using the original name as the "primary" name with the other names as the synonyms.

Comment: The ring example is little wrong, if i know correctly the original Japanese movie title is Ringu and American remake is The ring. And Second i also think the original title should be used as tag because most of the time the english dubbed title arises more trouble.

Comment: You're right - for some reason I thought the ring was called the ring in both instances, corrected my answer

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that, because our site is an English-based site, all title tags should be the English version of the title and that the original title from the non-English film should be added as a synonym to allow users to choose either tag.

So, in the recent example of the French film *La French* (US title *The Connection*) two tags were created the primary tag is [the-connection](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-connection) and the synonym was created for [la-french](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/la-french).

In the case that the American title is still in (or was always in) a foreign language, the title should be maintained... So *Chocolat*, the American film would have the tag [chocolat](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chocolat).

This occurs often with Indian films. Even when brought to the US and screened, the Hindi title is generally still better known and often the "official" title used on the English Wikipedia. Examples of this include films like *[Kuch Kuch Hota Hai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuch_Kuch_Hota_Hai)*. Wikipedia offers the title "Something Happens" but the film was marketed in the US under the original title.

This will require a little bit of work on our part (creating synonyms, determining which title was used when released in the US) but should make the tags more useful and more representative of our English focus.

Comment: Though, it can get really difficult if the title is different in different English speaking cultures, especially since we're actually not a US site but an English site. So I'm not sure going by the US marketed/released title is necessarily the most natural choice. In fact I prefer to go by the title that IMDb calls the "World wide (English)" title, if existing, unless the original is already in English.

Comment: Can you give an example?