# How should questions about movies with Roman numerals in their titles as a sequel indicator be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags

In my question, [How did Nomak learn about the supposedly secret location where Blade was being held?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/14458/1006) - about the film *[Blade II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_II)*, Christian Rau raised the following concern:

> @Community What to do with the blade-ii tag? While the official title
>   is indeed Blade II, that tag looks awful compared to blade-2, given
>   that this "II" is just a sequel number really.

So, how should questions about movies with roman numerals in their titles as a sequel indicator be tagged? Should they be tagged as they are originally titled, or should the Roman numerals be changed to their Arabic numeral counterparts, i.e. [blade-ii](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blade-ii) -> [blade-2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blade-2)? If it's the latter, can you explain why it should be done like that (aside from avoiding the tags "looking awful")?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the English title is a bit risky. O.K., we may start changing all the roman numerals, but then -- sooner or later -- there will be another "should we also change this?" question. Once we have one exception, why not having more? And then the whole system of what to translate and what not to translate will become overly complex.

I'd say we just leave the English titles, whatever they are, and make [blade-2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blade-2) a synonym for [blade-ii](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blade-ii). This practice might be useful for other sequels as well. For example, we can make [alien-2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alien-2) a synonym for [aliens](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens), making it easier to find tags (one need not know that "Alien: Resurrection" is the title of the movie that (s)he may know as "Alien 4"), while still being consistent with the "tag = title" approach.

Comment: I became more agree to you then my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

While being alienated by it at first, I tend to agree with your initial solution of [blade-ii](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blade-ii), since it captures the original title as accurately as possible (as also proposed in [this related discussion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1016/49)). While one could see it as *"just a sequel number"*, it is still part of the original title, in the same way as *Star Trek 2* isn't tagged [star-trek-2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-2) or [star-trek-2-wrath-of-khan](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-2-wrath-of-khan), but just [star-trek-wrath-of-khan](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-wrath-of-khan) and *Mighty Ducks 3* is tagged [d3-the-mighty-ducks](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d3-the-mighty-ducks) (disclaimer: I've done that), even if *"looking awful"* (which, I agree, is not a particularly sufficient reason).