# Should there be a specific tag for Zack Snyder's Justice League?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently the [Justice League](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/justice-league) tag says:

> 2017 American superhero movie about the team of comic superheroes of the same name as part of the DC Extended Universe

But the 2021 director's cut, which is even marketed as ["Zack Snyder's Justice League"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zack_Snyder%27s_Justice_League) is in many aspects significantly different from the 2017 theatrical version. Should it have its own tag?

Answer (score 4):

##### Yes: [zack-snyders-justice-league](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zack-snyders-justice-league)

According to our current policy, from community consensus in a top-voted answer in the meta FAQ post, [What's the policy on abbreviating titles of Movies & TV Shows?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1027/1006)

> If the original title fits into the limit, it is the only **objective criterium** by which one can go and thus should be **captured as accurately as possible**. And if it doesn't fit it is really a (maybe subjective) **movie by movie decision** driven by common sense, reading esthetics and archival purposes. And **meta appendages should only be used when actually necessary**.

Since the original and official title of the movie is "**Zack Snyder's Justice League**" (sources: [HBO](https://www.hbomax.com/feature/urn:hbo:feature:GYDAnZgCFQ8IJpQEAAAAN), [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt12361974/), [Rotten Tomatoes](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/zack_snyders_justice_league)), the tag should be [zack-snyders-justice-league](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zack-snyders-justice-league) ([which fits the tag character limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/162827)).

From the [same answer linked above](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1027/1006):

> Tag changes that extend tags by meta information in order to resolve ambiguities, like this `-tv` or the common year-appendages, should be **postponed until those ambiguities actually arise**.

[justice-league-2021](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/justice-league-2021) has an unnecessary meta year appendage, "2021" (which is not part of the official movie title), and according to our policy, should not be the main tag (since there is no ambiguity). It should be made a synonym of [zack-snyders-justice-league](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zack-snyders-justice-league) instead.

Comment: I think we should go with official title only with director name

Answer (score 3):

I asked myself the same question.

I think we *should* and suggest [justice-league-2021](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/justice-league-2021) which is in line with other "same name movies".

I note that SF&F has the tag [zack-snyders-justice-league](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zack-snyders-justice-league) so perhaps we should have both and I suggest the latter should be a synonym with [justice-league-2021](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/justice-league-2021)

Comment: Great suggestion.  Consistent with the way we tag movies here.