# Tag merge & synonym request: [guardians-of-the-galaxy-*] → [guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol.-*]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

According to our current tagging policy, as agreed by the community in the meta FAQ post, [What's the policy on abbreviating titles of Movies & TV Shows?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1027/1006)

> If the original title fits into the limit, it is the only **objective criterium** by which one can go and thus should be **captured as accurately as possible**.

Since the original and official titles of the movies are ***Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*** and ***Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3*** (with "**Vol.**"), I request to merge and synonymize the following tags to their official title versions:

| Current tag → | Official title with "Vol." tag |
| --- | --- |
| [guardians-of-the-galaxy-2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-of-the-galaxy-2) → | [guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol.-2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol.-2) |
| [guardians-of-the-galaxy-3](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-of-the-galaxy-3) → | [guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol.-3](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol.-3) |

[The tag character limit is currently 35 characters.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/162827) The *Guardians of the Galaxy* official title tags are 30 characters.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Thank you for creating the synonyms. One small thing: the tags need a period in “Vol.”. For example, it should be [[tag:guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol.-2]], not [[tag:guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2]]. Could you please fix that?

Comment: I noticed, yes. But I don't actually think we ever really did punctuation in tags. That was a concious decision.